# Remove everithing that it outside the brackets

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, text, regexp-replace

I need your help.

I working with Oracle SQL and I need to remove everything that it outside the brackets.
For example:

```
 - Stabilization loans, mortgage lending (StabL ML) => StabL ML
 - Refinanced loans and restructured loans (RefL RL) => RefL RL
 - Individual reserve (IR) => IR
```

I'm trying to use something like this but it doen't work

```
select regexp_replace(example, '\([A-Za-z ]\)', '') from dual;
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: What is your expected result based on your example?

Comment: Try ``[^()]*\(|\)[^()]*`` .

Comment: Or `REGEXP_SUBSTR(example, '\(([^()]*)\)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)`

Comment: I edited the message a bit to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

Although you [might consider](https://regex101.com/r/hKeKwI/1) using a pattern like `.*\(|\).*` with `REGEXP_REPLACE`, I'd rather you use

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(example, '\(([^()]*)\)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
```

See [the DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fk4U02Eb).

*Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other  than parentheses
- `\)` - a `)` char.

`1, 1, 'i', 1` make the regex engine search from the first char in the string only once (in a case insensitive way, though it is not quite important here) and the last `1` extracts Group 1 value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! both variants are working in Oracle! Maybe you know how to use it in Impala/Hive? They do not have regexp_substr but have regexp_replace and if I use it result has empty field

Comment: @Yurka In Impala: `regexp_extract(filepath, '\\(([^()]*)\\)', 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is partially correct. But you have to add the expression is "+"

'\([A-Za-z ]+\)'

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6we9jl/1)

or

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YjbABH/1)

'([A-Za-z].+)([(])([A-Za-z].+)([)])'

You can use the code as above with substitution "$3". But I think this code maybe more useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR ( 'Stabilization loans, mortgage lending (StabL ML)', '\( *([^)]*) *\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) FROM    dual;
```